# Kendo Angular SASS Builder: Colors

Tags: sass, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Using the SASS build for Kendo Angular Material I wish to simply change the primary, secondary and accent colors for the entire theme and then download.

There is only a drop down to select a color palette, but no way to choose specific colors.

When I download the variables.scss, there aren't entries for these three colors.

Question: How do I edit the variables.scss to change these three colors?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click the "<" on top of your screenshot, you can hide this panel and edit the colors.

If you're using npm, you can install the theme you want:

```
npm install @progress/kendo-theme-material
```

Then import the theme in your own scss file, where you can override some of the values:

```
$primary-palette-name: blue;
$secondary-palette-name: pink;
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.scss";
```

The documentation is here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/sass-themes

The variables are here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-themes/blob/develop/packages/material/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to create a new custom palette though, only pre-chosen values from the drop down.

Comment: @IanVink you can consider using the default theme instead, which doesn't have this limitation.